# Best way to translate parts of an existing site and retain page aliases

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

What is the least complicated way to translate parts of an existing and quite big site (few hundreds of thousands nodes), without affecting the page aliases?

I am aware of different translation systems and would prefer to use Entity translation. Unfortunately, it seems that both Entity Translation and Content translation don't make it possible to retain a functioning URL structure. E. g. I have this now:

- Original text's URL (the same pattern should work after translation): example.com/texto-original

After the translation work, it should have this structure:

- Original text's URL (the same pattern should work after translation): example.com/texto-original
- Translated text (has language parameter in the URL): example.com/en/translated-text

What I want to achieve:

1. There's a default language (Spanish in this example) that was used for all of the content so far. Those pages don't have language prefix in the URL (e. g. "es/") at the moment. It should stay that way.
2. Site should always display everything in Spanish, unless a visitor opens an URL with "en/" prefix.
3. On the pages that are translated, there should be a link "English", "View this page in English" or something similar.
4. When a visitor opens such page in English, there should also be a link "Español". If a visitor is on the English page - the interface, blocks and other entities (if translated) should be in English as well.

Sorry if I haven't explained well what I want to achieve, I'll try to explain better if something is not clear.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Internationalization (https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module to do this. You can manage to achieve your goal using this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and it's quite easy actually. Here are the steps necessary:

1. Go to languages settings: admin/config/regional/language
2. Edit the default language (the one that shouldn't have language prefix).
3. Remove the code from "Path prefix language code" field.
4. Go to detection options (admin/config/regional/language/configure) and select "URL" method.

That's it, it should work as I have described in the question.